# For some reason, my .click method is not working with <div id=menuButton>. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my html for a dropdown menu. Initially, in CSS the menu is on display: none; .

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>DropDown Menu</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

    <h1>DropDown Menu</h1>

    <div id="menuButton" >Menu Button</div>

    <div>
        <ul id="dropdown">

            <li>
                <a href=""></a>Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=""></a>Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=""></a>About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=""></a>Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=""></a>Partners</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>

        <!-- Load the CDN first -->
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

        <!-- If CDN fails to load, serve up the local version -->
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"><\/script>');</script>

        <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

And this is my jQuery script:

```
// script.js

$(function () {

$( "#menuButton" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dropdown" ).slideToggle();
});
});
```

The above jQuery does not work. However, if, inside the div I add a `<p>` tag with id= menuButton, it works perfectly fine. Could anyone please help me with this? I have been struggling for a while.

Comment: <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"><\/script> ? stray \?

Answer (score 1):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4b4yjkqs/), I have corrected some issues in your markup such as making

```
<a href=""></a>Home</a>
```

to

```
<a href="">Home</a>
```

Your code work fine otherwise

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in your code:

**1. Wait for DOM**

The problem is that your script is probably executed before the DOM is ready. You should trigger the script only once document is ready - i.e.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#menuButton" ).click(function() {
        $( "#dropdown" ).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Otherwise you are trying to add a click handler to a not-yet-existing #menuButton.

**2. Fix the `<a>` tags**

The following line of code

```
<a href=""></a>Home</a>
```

Should become:

```
<a href="">Home</a>
```

Do the same fix for other anchor tags as well.

Comment: According to http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp, we can simply write $(function () {...}); which is a short hand version for wrinting the whole document.ready liine

Answer (score 0):

Other than the markup issues in HTML, your code runs just fine as I have checked it via Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bryomckim/pmw7xjwf/

js

```
$(function () {
 $( "#menuButton" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dropdown" ).slideToggle();
 });
});
```

css

```
#dropdown {
 display: none;
}
```

Comment: So am I to assume it is an issue with my pc? Because it's not working on my chrome or firefox. Moreover, could it be because im using an older jQuery liibrary?

Comment: @ShravanNiranjan could you try serving the jquery from a CDN rather than  using the local one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>DropDown Menu</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
       <!-- Load the CDN first -->
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>     

        <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>DropDown Menu</h1>

    <div id="menuButton" >Menu Button</div>

    <div>
        <ul id="dropdown">

            <li>
                <a href=""></a>Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=""></a>Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=""></a>About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=""></a>Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=""></a>Partners</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```